# Google script - using template to build table

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-templates

Trying to build a report to be sent via email.
My idea was to build the email using an HTML template, but I seem to be missing out on something...
The email should contain a report which will include all entries with a specific month in ColB.

[Here's a quick demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JTTmMRoCG8NbyZFDV8svQuoepZbYroRYw0N2IySueAg/edit?usp=sharing)

Here's my code

```js
function MonthlyPulseCheck() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var pulsedate = new Date("02/02/2022"); 
  var pulsemonth = pulsedate.getMonth();
  var Pulsetable = buildmonthlypulse(pulsemonth);
  
  var emailtemplate  = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Monthly pulse check');
    emailtemplate.OOOPULSE = Pulsetable;
  
  var emailbody = emailtemplate.evaluate();
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail('someone@gmail.com',( 'monthly pulse check for month ' + pulsemonth), '',
                     {htmlBody: emailbody.getContent(),
      name: 'test system', 
      from: 'alias@gmail.com', 
      replyTo: 'alias2@gmail.com',
})
}

function buildmonthlypulse(pulsemonth) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var Pulsearray = spreadsheet.getRange('A2:C').getValues();
var i = 0;
var counter = 1;
var imax = 15;//Pulsearray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < imax; i++) {
var arraydate = new Date(Pulsearray[i][1]);
var arraymonth = arraydate.getMonth();
//var pulseHTML = 0;
//var checkdate = new Date(arraydate);
if (arraymonth === pulsemonth) {
  if (counter === 1) {
  var pulseHTML = '<table style="float: right;"> <body> <tr> <td>&nbsp;TEXT2</td> <td>&nbsp;TEXT</td> <td><a href="ynet.co.il">&nbsp;NAME</a></td> </tr>'
  }
  var name =  spreadsheet.getRange(i+2, 1).getValue();
  var namelink = 'google.com';
  
  var pulseHTML = pulseHTML + '  <tr> <td>&nbsp;1</td> <td>&nbsp;2</td> <td><a href="youtube.com">&nbsp;3</a></td> </tr>';
  var counter = counter + 1;
  }
  
  }
  if (counter != 1) {
  var pulseHTML = pulseHTML + '</tbody> </table>';
  }
  return pulseHTML;
  }
```

Here's the HTML (used as a template)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?=OOOPULSE?>
  </body>
</html>
```

email is sent with just the digit 0 in the body.
Can anyone make sense of this?

Comment: I think it's likely something wrong with your function `buildmonthlypulse(pulsemonth)`  for one thing I'd change your range `spreadsheet.getRange(2,1,spreadsheat.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();` because with it the way you have it your likely getting a lot of extra null lines at the bottom.

Comment: Try building your text with `Utilities.formatString()`

Comment: Thanks for this input. I think I have a handle on this now, apart from the following:
I'm trying to "build" a link to a specific range inside a Sheet. So, I'm building something like this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XXXXXX/edit#gid=99999999&range=A2:D2
The build is working fine but when it runs through the template and evaluate process something is lost and the "&" turns into "%E2%A6%A5". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I tried to replicate your code and found some issues:**

1. In your `function buildmonthlypulse()`, you declared `var pulseHTML` multiple times inside the `for loop` which is not accessible to the return statement.
2. In your HTML file, you are using [Printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets) `<?= ... ?>` which is use for printing values with contextual escaping. The html elements in your `var pulseHTML` are recognized as string.

**Solution:**

1. Declare `var pulseHTML = ''` above the for loop statement (just like the commented one) and inside the for loop, remove `var` and retain `pulseHTML`. *Example:* `pulseHTML = pulseHTML + '</tbody> </table>';`
2. Instead of using Printing scriptlets `"<?= ... ?>"` use [Force-printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets) `<?!= ... ?>`. It is the same with Printing scriptlets but avoid contextual escaping.

Example Output:

**Using Printing scriptlets**

[image]

**Using Force-printing scriptlets**

[image]

Nitpick:

- Replace `<body>` with `<tbody>` in the `pulseHTML = '<table style="float: right;"> <body> <tr>....` of your code.
- [Proper indentation](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse154/17au/styleguide/js/spacing-indentation-js.html#:%7E:text=Spacing%20and%20indentation%20should%20be,than%20the%20previous%20line%27s%20indentation.).

---

### References:

- [Contextual escaping](https://olddocs.phalcon.io/en/2.0.0/reference/escaper)
- [Printing scriptlets and Force-printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets)
- [Variable scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: Thanks for this input. I think I have a handle on this now, apart from the following: I'm trying to "build" a link to a specific range inside a Sheet. So, I'm building something like this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XXXXXX/edit#gid=99999999&range=A2:D2 The build is working fine but when it runs through the template and evaluate process something is lost and the "&" turns into "%E2%A6%A5". Any thoughts?

Comment: @user13708028 - Kindly create a separate post for it as it is not related to the original post. You can link this post to your new post for reference.

Comment: Understood. Here's a link to the new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65311615/html-lost-during-evaluation-process